# codeigniter mysql query syntax

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

```
$assetcheckbox=$_POST['assetcheckbox'];
foreach($assetcheckbox as $assetcheckbox)
        {

        $query=$this->db->query('select a2.email_id from users a2,assets a1 where a1.status="In transit" and a1.serial_no IN ("$assetcheckbox") and a1.tmploc=a2.location group by a2.email_id');
        $queryresult=$query->result();
        var_dump($queryresult);
        }
```

i am getting empty value in var_dump.

same query its showing output if i run in phpmyadmin.

Kindly help.

Comment: Foreach loop is working?  have you tries query echo inside foreach once?

Comment: `foreach($assetcheckbox as $assetcheckbox)` same array name as element name. change it. php array is passing into the query. `foreach($assetcheckbox as $assetcheckboxelement)` Check this after query `echo($this->db->get_compiled_select());`

Comment: What does `$assetcheckbox` look like? Is it an array? Is it an array of arrays? You should replace `IN ("$assetcheckbox")` by `IN (?)`. If it is a single array, you do not need the `foreach`. Change your query call to `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY', array($assetcheckbox));`. If it is an array of arrays, change the second `$assetcheckbox` after `as` in the `foreach` to `$asset`, for instance, and again `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY', array($asset));`